# Leptonica compilation error

Tags: make, tesseract

Trying to install leptonica v1.78 on Ubuntu 16, but it's not working for some reason. After running `./configure` and `make`, I keep getting this error:

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/user/Documents/leptonica/leptonica-1.78.0/prog'
  CC       convertfilestopdf.o
  CCLD     convertfilestopdf
../src/.libs/liblept.so: undefined reference to `lzham_z_version'
../src/.libs/liblept.so: undefined reference to `lzham_z_deflateInit'
../src/.libs/liblept.so: undefined reference to `lzham_z_inflate'
../src/.libs/liblept.so: undefined reference to `lzham_z_deflate'
../src/.libs/liblept.so: undefined reference to `lzham_z_deflateEnd'
../src/.libs/liblept.so: undefined reference to `lzham_z_inflateInit'
../src/.libs/liblept.so: undefined reference to `lzham_z_inflateEnd'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:2603: recipe for target 'convertfilestopdf' failed
make[2]: *** [convertfilestopdf] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user/Documents/leptonica/leptonica-1.78.0/prog'
Makefile:476: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/Documents/leptonica/leptonica-1.78.0'
Makefile:385: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I think I installed all the dependencies needed, am I missing something?

Comment: it appears you are still missing some libraries - do you have all dependencies as listed here? https://www.lucacerone.net/2017/installing-tesseract-3-0-5-on-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: Yep all installed, turns out it had to do with using the ```make-for``` files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out how, had to use `make-for-local` to compile properly. Not sure if it's just my case because I don't see many guides using this.

```
./configure
./make-for-local
sudo make
./make-for-auto
sudo make install
sudo make -j4 check
```